# collapse On Select React Bootstrap Navbar with nextjs not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

I am using the react bootsrtap NavBar with NextJs but the collapse on select is not working,
The navbar is not collapsing when I press any link, it just navigates without collapsing.

```
import React from "react";
import { Nav, Navbar, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Link from "next/link";
import stylesNav from "./Navbar.module.css";

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
   <div>
      <Navbar
        collapseOnSelect
        fixed="top"
        className={stylesNav.topNavbar}
        expand="md"
        bg="dark"
        variant="dark"
      >
        <Container className={stylesNav.Cont}>
          <div className={stylesNav.scmpLogoNavbar}>
            <Link eventKey="0" href="/">
              <a className={` ${stylesNav.SCMP1}  ${stylesNav.Links}`}>SCMP</a>
            </Link>
          </div>

          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className={'me-auto'}></Nav>
            <Nav>

              <Link eventKey="1" href="/">
                <a className={stylesNav.navlink}>Home</a>
              </Link>

              <Link
                className={stylesNav.navlink}
                eventKey="2"
                href="/Departments"
              >
                <a className={stylesNav.navlink} >Departments</a>
              </Link>

              <Link
                className={stylesNav.navlink}
                eventKey="3"
                href="/Events"
              >
                <a className={stylesNav.navlink}>Events</a>
              </Link>

              <Link
                className={stylesNav.navlink}
                eventKey="3"
                href="/SWS"
              >
                <a className={stylesNav.navlink}>Startup-Weekend</a>

              </Link>

              <Link className={stylesNav.navlink} eventKey="4" href="/auth">
                <a className={stylesNav.navlink}>Login</a>
              </Link>

            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
);
}
```

I think the problem is from next/link.
Using `<Link>` without a `<a>` inside it doesn't render any text inside it
and Using `<Nav.Link as={Link} href="/" to="/"></Nav.Link>` also doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that you set up a https://codesandbox.io/ with an example? Then I'd love to look into it.

Comment: I would. but I already solved it, thank you a lot. The solution was to wrap each <Nav.Link></Nav.Link> with a <Link> but with a passHref prop as follows :

Comment: <Link  eventKey="1"  href="/"  passHref>
              <Nav.Link className={stylesNav.navlink}>Home</Nav.Link>  
              </Link>

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
    <Link  eventKey="1"  href="/"  passHref>
    <Nav.Link className={stylesNav.navlink}>Home</Nav.Link>  
    </Link>
```

wrap each `Nav.Link`  with  `Link` tag but with the `passHref` prop